# How to provide feedback to WPF during dynamic loading of the View portion of MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

For research I've read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/october/wpf-threads-build-more-responsive-apps-with-the-dispatcher) and have written many applications using `BackgroundWorker`.  No articles have any information on how to update the UI while loading the UI.  I've created my own `BusyIndicator` (since this is lacking in WPF) but it also fails to update while the UI is updating. I'm certain I'm not the first person to create the UI dynamically so this has to have been solved by someone, somewhere but I'm unable to find it.

I'd like to provide feedback to the users as the dynamic UI loads.  First some background.  The application is a conversion from a JavaScript app (via Typescript) that was originally written in Silverlight.  The application reads a "View" as XML and then dynamically creates/loads controls in the XMAL.  It is during this process that I would like to provide some feedback, but since the loading of controls in the UI is actually on the UI thread, and feedback is also on the UI thread there is no effective communication presented to the users.

I have tried using the dispatcher to invoke a delegate both on the main UI thread or for an individual UI Element (ProgressBar).  Using either of these methods does update, but only after the everything else has finished.

I have not tried using a background thread, because as the XML is parsed each control is created and added to the XMAL which needs to be on the UI thread.

Can someone provide me with a possible solution?  Is there a way to force my busy indicator to update while still loading the UI?

EDIT: supplying requested code

What actually happens is the user selects from a couple of Combo boxes in order to supply the data system and view of the data system they are interested in.  When the view has been selected, a query is run to obtain the XML from the database. The XML defines things like the type of control, location, size and alarm values, alarm colors etc..  We currently have over 1000 different views for the users to select from and some of these views contain 1000's of controls.

In the code snippet below a single control type is being created dynamically, MT_BoxTextCtrl, which is a simple label and readonly text box.  Obviously the actual code is considerably more complex and includes parsing the xml, but this shows basically what happens.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //simulate reading of xml.  Here we just put in labels, Textboxs and new tabItems
        TabItem aTab = null;
        Canvas activeCanvas = null;
        int tabHeader = 1;
        for(int i=0, c=0, r=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            // the XML parser would read the xml which contains nodes to define new tabs and the controls contiained within the tab
            // here we are just simulating what occurs, ie create the tab/scrollViewer and canvas.  Then add controls to it.
            if(i%250 == 0)
            {
                aTab = new TabItem();
                aTab.Header = "TabItem " + tabHeader;
                tabHeader++;
                ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
                activeCanvas = new Canvas();
                activeCanvas.Name = String.Format("_Canvas{0}", _TabCtrl.Items.Count);
                activeCanvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                activeCanvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                activeCanvas.Height = 0D;
                activeCanvas.Width = 0D;
                sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
                sv.Content = activeCanvas;
                aTab.Content = sv;
                _TabCtrl.Items.Add(aTab);
                r = c = 0;
            }
            MT_BoxTextCtrl ctrl = new MT_BoxTextCtrl();
            ctrl.Label = "Gauge " + i.ToString();
            ctrl.Location = new Point(c * 200, r * 40);
            ctrl.Width = 200;
            ctrl.Height = 40;
            ctrl.LblLocation = OpsViewer.Classes.MT_Helper.Loc.left;
            activeCanvas.Children.Add(ctrl);
            Canvas.SetLeft(ctrl, ctrl.Location.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(ctrl, ctrl.Location.Y);
            if (activeCanvas.Height < ctrl.Location.Y + ctrl.Height)
                activeCanvas.Height = ctrl.Location.Y + ctrl.Height + 10;

            if (activeCanvas.Width < ctrl.Location.X + ctrl.Width)
                activeCanvas.Width = ctrl.Location.X + ctrl.Width + 100;


            r++;

            if (r > 20)
            {
                r = 0;
                c++;
            }

        }

    }
```

And here is the complete MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<TabControl x:Name="_TabCtrl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="2,2,2,2" Background="{x:Null}">

</TabControl>
```

You will notice working this way provides another level of abstraction since the View is not even actually defined in the application and can be quickly created/modified without having to redistribute the client.  In the same way the MVVM model removes the Data from the View, now I've removed the View from the application.

It all works but it takes upwards of 5 to 10 seconds to create the controls.  During this time the UI thread is busy doing its work or making controls.

My question remains how do I provide user feedback during this "Loading" time.

Comment: Perhaps with an elevated Dispatcher priority or an animation.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/october/wpf-threads-build-more-responsive-apps-with-the-dispatcher

Comment: I have read the article.  It does not address the issue of how to both provide feedback and dynamically create the UI simultaneously

Comment: What you're most likely looking for is `async` `await`.  To provide more detailed advice, I'd need to see a bit of your code.  Read "How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Yes.  Show us how you build the UI.  Ie is it all on the UI thread or does it into the Dispatcher for each control, or load XAML from disk, etc?

Comment: The xml is not XAML.  the xml describes the dynamic content, i.e. which custom controls to create, where to place them, and the data needed to obtain the value to display in the control.  The same xml is used to create the javascript controls and the wpf controls.  WPF is needed because of limited bandwidth (satellite) in some locations.  WPF client is used to display their own data, rather than system wide data in the JS browser app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to create a second application that ran in its own thread.  From the main application I would open the Windows Forms, form that contained a ProgressBar and a label.  As progress proceeded I would would 'Step the bar' and change the label.

The code I used was originally designed as a splash screen for another application.  While thinking about the problem more I realized a splash screen actually is what I was looking for since it provides feedback while the code initializes.  For this particular solution I simply modified the splash screen to look more like a feedback dialog and bring it up when ever a new "view" is loaded by the user.